# Ask the reasoning behind this method to get eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a statistics textbook. The derived correlation matrix is

$$\textbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}1&.4\\.4&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the textbook said the eigenvalue is $1+\rho = 1.4$ and $1-\rho = .6$. I feel curious what the reasoning behind the $1+\rho$ and $1-\rho$.

Comment: Yeah, you’ve got confused two different variables.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for the matrix should be $(1 - \lambda)^2 - 0.4^2.$ Solving for its zeroes should give you $1 - \lambda = \pm 0.4 \leftrightarrow \lambda = 1 \pm 0.4$

Comment: The bold $\rho$ denotes the matrix and the plain $\rho$ means 2variable's correlation: 0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $$B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues $\pm1$ with eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\\pm1\end{pmatrix}.$

So $$\begin{pmatrix}1&\alpha\\\alpha&1\end{pmatrix}=I+\alpha B$$

Has eigenvalues $1\pm \alpha,$ with the same eigenvectors.